# Get the concrete instance of ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IReleaseDataProvider>().To<ReleaseDataProvider>().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", _connectionString);    

ninjectKernel.Bind<IReleaseService>().To<ReleaseService>().WithConstructorArgument("releaseDataProvider", releaseDataProvider);
```

How can I get the releaseDataProvider instance which should be passed in the Constructor of the releaseService class?

Comment: If you only register one `IReleaseDataProvider` and in the `ReleaseService` constructor you have `IReleaseDataProvider` then the call `ninjectKernel.Bind<IReleaseService>().To<ReleaseService>();` will exactly do what you want. No need for additional config.

Comment: Have you seen my connectionString instance ? How should this work with your advise?

Comment: ah my failure. I re-read the comment again and now I understand. Yes thats the purpose of a di tool. resolve the dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IReleaseDataProvider>().To<ReleaseDataProvider>().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", _connectionString); 

ninjectKernel.Bind<IReleaseService>().To<ReleaseService>();
```

No need to pass/get the releaseDataProvider manually.

When the ReleaseService instance is created its constructor parameter instance (ReleaseDataProvider) and those dependencies(connectionString) will be resolved